# Define a Label Asp.net Coordinates through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, web-controls

I need to create dinamically a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label and define its cordinates in the Asp.net Page.

I know it absolute position (x,y). But i dont know any way to define it.
Here is how i create the label:

```
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label box3 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
        box3.Text = entradas.ElementAt(0).text;
        box3.ID = "box3";
        //need to define x and y here
```

The question is how to define its position.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you ever heard of [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)?

Comment: Yes i did, but i cant use it for what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Label` control has an [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx) property which you can use to define the labels position on the front end.

For example: -

```
label.Attributes.Add("style", "top:10; right:10; position:absolute;");
```

Alternatively, you could just apply some CSS to the rendered HTML...

Comment: that coordinates are absolute? i cant use css in this situation

Comment: You can add a [position](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101) rule which specifies whether it should be displayed `relative, absolute.. etc...`

Comment: relative to what ? a container ?
You can still use CSS. it is your only way actually

Comment: Ok ty for the fast answer, it happened that i googled a lot and didn't find anything, weird when the solution was this simple

Comment: No problem. I still think applying the style through a stylesheet would be better than this though..