# ‘label’ does not contain a definition for ‘Name’ and no extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am getting this error message on the code below:

> ‘label’ does not contain a definition for ‘Name’ and no extension
>   method ‘Name’ accepting a first argument type of label could be found.
>   (are you missing or using directive or an assembly  reference?)

It is in regards to `lbl.Name` and `lbl.Location` but I have no idea why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace budgetTracker
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        static int i = 1;

        protected void saveSalaryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            monthlySalaryLabel.Text = "$" + salaryInput.Text;
        }

        private void addExpense()
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = "expense" + i.ToString();
            lbl.Text = expenseNameInput.Text;
            lbl.Location = new Point(15, 15);
            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            expenseNameInput.Text = String.Empty;
        }

        protected void addExpenseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addExpense();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `asp:Label` belongs to the name space `System.Web.UI.WebControls`, in that class there is no property called `Name`. For uniquely identify that control you should use `ID` instead for Name, So the code will be:

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.ID= "expense" + i.ToString(); // Change is here
lbl.Text = expenseNameInput.Text;  
this.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

For fixing the location of the control in the container, I think the better option for you is to use styling. Try something like this:

```
lbl.Style.Add("width","40px");
lbl.Style.Add("top", "10px");
```

Comment: Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I didn't see a property "location" on the msdn page, is it a valid one?

Comment: Here is a helpful link for location, maybe add it to the answer: [Define a Label Asp.net Coordinates through C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17524100/6741868)

Answer (score 0):

**In label  class there is no property called Name**

Comment: Is this not the correct MSDN page? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GarrettPenfield - No, that's the documentation for the Windows Forms Label control, not the asp one.